# How to load plugin for s3 bucket with Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I have a nuxt app with a few third party plugins, gsap, splitting.js, etc.. All of the plugins work fine as they should.

I have a simple-keyboard plugin loading in the same way as the others, it loads fine locally but after I run `nuxt generate` and upload my dist folder to the s3 bucket, the keyboard/plugin does not show up. There are also no errors in console. I'm not sure what is removing it?

I have created a file in the plugins directory like so:

`plugins/simple-keyboard.js`

In my `nuxt.config.js` file I have placed:

```
plugins: [
    { src: '~plugins/fastclick.js', ssr: false },
    { src: '~plugins/splitting.js', ssr: false },
    { src: '~plugins/simple-keyboard.js', ssr: false },
    { src: '~plugins/maskedinput.js', ssr: false }
  ],
```

Here is the contents of my `plugins/simple-keyboard.js` file:

```
import Keyboard from 'simple-keyboard';
import inputMask from "simple-keyboard-input-mask";
import 'simple-keyboard/build/css/index.css';

if(window.location.pathname == '/welcome') {
  let keyboard = new Keyboard({
    onChange: input => onChange(input),
    onKeyPress: button => onKeyPress(button),
    layout: {
      default: ["1 2 3", "4 5 6", "7 8 9", "{C} 0 "],
      shift: [" ABC DEF", "GHI JKL MNO", "PQRS TUV WXYZ"]
    },
    theme: "keyboard hg-theme-default hg-layout-numeric numeric-theme",
    disableCaretPositioning: true,
    inputMask: "(888) 888-8888",
    modules: [inputMask],
    syncInstanceInputs: true
  })

  let backspace = new Keyboard(".backspace", {
    onChange: input => onChange(input),
    onKeyPress: button => onKeyPress(button),
    layout: {
      default: ["{bksp}"]
    },
    mergeDisplay: true,
    display: {
      '{bksp}': '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
    },
    theme: "hg-theme-default hg-layout-numeric numeric-theme",
    syncInstanceInputs: true
  })

  function onChange(input) {
    document.querySelector(".input").value = input;
  }

  function clearKeyboard() {
    keyboard.clearInput();
    document.querySelector(".input").value = '';
  }

  function onKeyPress(button) {
    if (button === "{C}") clearKeyboard();
  }

}
```

Locally everything works perfectly fine. 
Even when I host it on a local PHP server and point to the dist file. everything runs fine. 
When I run my build command and deploy the contents to my S3 bucket, everything works aside from the keyboard. It simply doesn't render.

I cannot figure out how to get the simple-keyboard plugin to properly render when deployed to S3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the creator of simple-keyboard, and just wanted to update this entry as it was resolved on a Discord chat.

The issue was in this line of code:

```
if(window.location.pathname == '/welcome') { ...
```

In the local environment, the `pathname` was indeed `/welcome`. However, once pushed to the server, the `pathname` became `/welcome/` so the code never got to the part where the keyboard is instantiated.

Hope that helps anyone who encounters a similar issue.

Comment: Correct! Thank you so much